# How many Krueger flaps does the 737-700 have?

Tags: boeing-737, flaps

How many Krueger flaps does the 737-700 have? It has inboard krueger flaps, but I'm trying to make out if it has one or two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has **4 Krueger flaps** (2 on each wing) and 8 slats (4 on each wing):

> LE devices consist of four flaps and eight slats: two flaps inboard and four slats
> outboard of each engine.

<sup>(Boeing 737 NG FCOMv2 9.20.20 - Flight Controls - System Description - Flaps and Slats)</sup>

You can see the Krueger flaps in the following image (thanks to ymb1 for the link):

[image: 737-800]
<sup>(cropped from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bangladesh_Biman_Boeing_737-800_(S2-AFL)_(7520028824).jpg), CC BY-SA 2.0)</sup>